# Any faster method to get Volume Serial number?

Tags: .net, vb.net, wmi

Hi I'm using this code to generate machine signature. But it's take noticeable time to execute.  Wonder why it's that slow ?  Any faster method recommended ?

```
Public Shared Function DriveSN(ByVal DriveLetter As String) As String
    Dim disk As ManagementObject = New ManagementObject(String.Format("Win32_Logicaldisk='{0}'", DriveLetter))
    Dim VolumeName As String = disk.Properties("VolumeName").Value.ToString()
    Dim SerialNumber As String = disk.Properties("VolumeSerialnumber").Value.ToString()
    Return SerialNumber.Insert(4, "-")
End Function

Private Shared msig As String = Nothing

Public Shared Function MachineSignature() As String
    If msig Is Nothing Then
        Dim list As New List(Of String)
        For Each d As DriveInfo In DriveInfo.GetDrives()
            If (d.IsReady) Then
                list.Add(DriveSN(d.Name.Substring(0, 2)))
            End If
        Next
        msig = String.Join(" & ", list.ToArray())
    End If
    Return msig
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is embarrassing. The performance problem can be solved by simply check for "fixed" drive.

```
Public Shared Function MachineSignature() As String
    If msig Is Nothing Then
        Dim list As New List(Of String)
        For Each d As DriveInfo In DriveInfo.GetDrives()
            If (d.DriveType = DriveType.Fixed) AndAlso (d.IsReady) Then  ' <-- check for DriveType'
                list.Add(DriveSN(d.Name.Substring(0, 2)))
            End If
        Next
        msig = String.Join(" & ", list.ToArray())
    End If
    Return msig
End Function
```

Comment: How did you discover that was the problem?

Comment: Stepping through debugger.  The "IsReady" checking for other kind of drives (floppy, cd-rom) can take noticeable pause.

Nothing mystery here.

Answer (score 3):

There is a .Net way also from [egghead cafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10062715/hdds-serial-number.aspx) using the System.Management namespace.

Firstly, you need to add the reference to the System.Management dll in vb.net. Using the Project->Add Reference menu item.

Then the following code gets the drive serial number for the C drive:

```
Dim drive As String = "C"
Dim disk As System.Management.ManagementObject = _
       New System.Management.ManagementObject _
       ("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=""" + drive + ":""")
disk.Get()
Dim SerialNumber as String = disk("VolumeSerialNumber").ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Win32 API call to this also, but i think WMI is the better way since it's still managed code.

Win32 API function: [GetVolumeInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364993%28VS.85%29.aspx)

I found the following function on [eggheadcafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20021019.asp) (it's C#, but should be not problem to do in vb.net) to extract the Serial number:

```
public string GetVolumeSerial(string strDriveLetter)
{
uint serNum = 0;
uint maxCompLen = 0;
StringBuilder VolLabel = new StringBuilder(256); // Label
UInt32 VolFlags = new UInt32();
StringBuilder FSName = new StringBuilder(256); // File System Name
strDriveLetter+=":\\"; // fix up the passed-in drive letter for the API call
long Ret = GetVolumeInformation(strDriveLetter, VolLabel, (UInt32)VolLabel.Capacity, ref serNum, ref maxCompLen, ref VolFlags, FSName, (UInt32)FSName.Capacity);

return Convert.ToString(serNum);
}
```

Comment: You need to include the declarations for GetVolumeInformation as well for this code to work.